# n number of loops where n is not known

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nested-loops, razorengine

I have the following `Entity Framework` class with a column which is a `Foreign Key` to the `Primary Key` in the same table:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public long ItemID { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public long? ItemParentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemParentID")]
    public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }

}
```

The mapping above works great and I am able to get all the children items in the `Children` property to the nth level simply by passing the `ItemParentID` and selecting the `Items`.

Now I have to bind this data along with all the children items and their children items etc. in my `razor` view. I have started with the following code:

```
@if (Model.ChildItems.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Item parentItem in Model.ChildItems)
        {
            <div class="list-title">
                <span>@parentItem.ItemName</span>
                <ul>
                    @if (parentItem.Children.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (Item childItem in parentItem.Children)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@FrontEndDomain.GetWebsiteURL()/@childItem.ItemID/details/@FrontEndDomain.GetURLString(Model.ParentItemName)/@FrontEndDomain.GetURLString(childItem.ItemName)" title="@childItem.ItemName">
                                    @childItem.ItemName
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li>
                            No items available for @parentItem.ItemName.
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <h4>No items available.</h4>
    }
```

The above code works well with 2 levels of children items but I want to bind data of all the child items and their child items to nth level. I have checked other questions on `SO` but they are complex and most of them doesn't deal with `lists` like `Children` property mentioned above. Any simple way to get this done?

Comment: What you need is a recursive function. One option would be to create a HtmlHelper extension method as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744)

Comment: Hmmm... You could try using an `@helper` method to render this recursively.  Pass in the current node as parameter, then iterate and render children.  Example of `@helper` syntax here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/6532107/4322803

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the other answers on SO don't deal with lists containing lists - there's not that many other options. Can you post the links to the ones you looked at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursive use `Html.RenderPartial` helper like this(it is just [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iIYcji), without your specific markup):

**View:**

```
@model Item

<p>@Model.ItemName</p>
<ul>
    @if (Model.Children != null && Model.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var child in Model.Children)
        {
            <li>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("Index", child);}
            </li>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <li>
            No items available for @Model.ItemName.
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this quite nicely with a recursive partialview.

**RecursivePartial.cshtml:**

```
@model Item

<span>@Model.ItemName</span>
<ul>
    @if (Model.Children?.Any() ?? false)
    {
        foreach (var child in Model.Children)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.Partial("RecursivePartial", child)
            </li>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <li>
            No items available for @Model.ItemName.
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

You could then call this partialview from wherever you need

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

@if (Model?.Any() ?? false)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("RecursivePartial", item)
    }
}
else
{
    <h4>No items available.</h4>
}
```

Comment: You are wrong, I wrote my answer at the same time you did.