# Migrate html helpers to ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper

I'm converting a project to ASP.NET Core. I need to migrate lots of reusable html helpers, but html helpers do not exist in Core.

Some are complex, some simple. Here's a extremely simple example:

```
@helper EditIcon()
{
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
}
```

Note that this is only an example.

*Point is writing a tag helper for that is gigantic overkill.* Same for partials. Same for view components.

We're talking about a little snippet of Razor. What is my best option?

Comment: not exist? are you sure?

Comment: @Alex I read it in multiple places. Also when I try it, I get `The helper directive is not supported.`

Comment: `@helper` has been removed in core-mvc - you need to use view components etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke So my options: 1) tag helpers, 2) partials, 3) view components. That's it? Something else I don't know about perhaps?

Comment: AFAIK, that's it (IMHO the old `@helper` was an mistake by MVC team anyway and its good to see they are gone)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the confirmation. Though I disagree to the removal - little snippets of markup I can create without jumping through hoops was great, for our needs.

Comment: So sad to see one really useful feature messed up...

Comment: Stunned to read they are gone and no suitable equivalent where you can get re-use within a view and still get Razor-like syntax.  I have helpers throughout my legacy site for a good reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>So, seems there are only three options:</strike>

- [tag helpers](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro)
- [partials](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial)
- [view components](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components)

So no simple way to migrate Razor snippets, without jumping through hoops.

---

*EDIT*

So [looks like](http://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/715#issuecomment-198456302) html helpers [are available](http://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/715#issuecomment-200639733) after all. They just haven't been properly documented!

Comment: Only supported locally. No way to share it between views.

Comment: Helpers are not available at all, the text is misleading which made me read the whole conversation. The team specifically said they don't plan on bringing them back.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159904/1942917 - https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/344/what-happened-to-helpers-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 15):

@helper directive is removed, but if you may consider using `Func<dynamic, IHtmlContent>` you are migrating a legacy code. Here is an example:

```
@{
    Func<dynamic, IHtmlContent> BrowserInfo(string btitle, string href, string imgfilename) =>
        @<div style="text-align: center">
            <a href="@href">
                <img src="~/content/images/browsers/@imgfilename" alt="@btitle"/>@btitle</a>
        </div>;
}
```

And use it just like old helper methods:

```
@BrowserInfo("Google Chrome", "http://www.google.com/chrome/", "browser_chrome.gif")(null)
```

Comment: This won't work if you just copy/paste this example. You'll need to use `@BrowserInfo("Google Chrome", "http://www.google.com/chrome/", "browser_chrome.gif")(null)` to accomodate for the `dynamic` parameter in the Func.

Comment: How to get rid of the semicolon at the end?

Comment: How do I share it between multiple views?

Answer (score 14):

Personally I think this approach is cleaner for small in-page snippets:

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/344/what-happened-to-helpers-in-asp-net-core

> [...] One of those things is a more formal replacement for the Razor
>   helper. You can now include HTML markup in the body of a method
>   declared in a code block as a local method as previously, or in an
>   @functions block. The method should return void, or Task if it
>   requires asynchronous processing. Here is how the list helper is
>   written in ASP.NET Core 3:

```
@{
    void Template(string[] listItems, string style) 
    {
        <ul>
        foreach (var listItem in listItems)
        {
            <li class="@style">@listItem</li>
        }
        </ul>
    }
}
```

and place it like this:

```
@{ Template(new[] { "A","B","C" },  "pretty" ); }
```

Answer (score 10):

I have successfully converted ASP.NET MVC Razor Helpers to Function Directives in .NET CORE 3.1 as an example shown below:

**E.g.**
**ASP.NET MVC 5 @helper syntax:**

```
<div>
       @RenderHello();
</div>


@helper RenderHello() {
        <strong>Hello</strong>
}
```

**Equivalent ASP.NET CORE 3.1 @functions directive syntax:**

```
<div>
    <text>
    @{
        RenderHello();
    }
    </text>
</div>

@functions {
    private void RenderHello()
    {
        <strong>Hello</strong>
    }
}
```

[Razor Function Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#functions)